# display WP image posts in Bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: post-thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of image posts displayed on a page of a WP site that uses Bootstrap 4

The images normally display in a larger size when they're clicked on but I want to display them in a dropdown modal _ The problem is that when I implement the modal it only displays the last post on the page NOT the image that was clicked on _

I realise this is because I need to get the post ID and add the same ID to the modal code _ However, I have tried several ways of doing this but not been successful

this is the code I currently have on the page >>>

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        
        <div class="container fadeIn" id="perimeter">
            
            <section class="gallery" id="mainGallery">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php $featured_query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'category_name' => 'canvas'
                        )); ?>
                        
                        <?php while($featured_query->have_posts()) : 
                            $featured_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="divPad">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galleryModal" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                            <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>    
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                        <span class="fontBrand1 fontType1 text"><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
                                        <span class="fontBrand2 fontOpenSans smallText"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Materials', true); ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Dimensions', true); ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?></span>
                                    </div><!-- /.divPad -->
                                </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                   
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </section><!-- /#mainGallery -->
            
            <div class="horizBuffer2"></div>
        </div><!-- /#perimeter -->
        
        <!-- modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="galleryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="galleryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="galleryModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /#galleryModal -->
        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated _ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realise this is because I need to get the post ID and add the same
>   ID to the modal code

No, that's not true in your case. If you want to use a *single* modal for all the different images — i.e. a different image is displayed in the modal *based on the button/link which triggers the modal* (or simply, the button/link that was clicked), you need JavaScript to achieve that, just as what stated in the [Bootstrap 4's Modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) — and after all, the modal itself is a JavaScript plugin:

> ### Varying modal content
>
> Have a bunch of buttons that all trigger the same modal with slightly
>   different contents? Use `event.relatedTarget` and HTML `data-*`
>   attributes (possibly via jQuery) to vary the contents of the modal
>   depending on which button was clicked.

So based on the example [there](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) and your code:

**Option 1:** You can simply use this script to replace the modal content with the inner HTML of the button/link which triggers the modal:

```js
jQuery( function( $ ){
    $( '#galleryModal' ).on( 'show.bs.modal', function ( event ) {
        var button = $( event.relatedTarget ); // Button/link that triggered the modal
        var modal = $( this );

        // Update the modal's content.
        modal.find('.modal-body').html(
            button.html()
        );
    });
});
```

**Option 2:** Or use the `data-*` attribute for more control such as displaying a larger preview of the post thumbnail. And here I use `data-image` and `large` as the thumbnail size:

1. Add the `data-image`: (wrapped for clarity)

   ```php
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galleryModal" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"
     data-image="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ); ?>">
   ```

   *See the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) if you need help with the `the_post_thumbnail_url()`.*
2. Add the script: (take note of the new `image` variable)

   ```js
   jQuery( function( $ ){
       $( '#galleryModal' ).on( 'show.bs.modal', function ( event ) {
           var button = $( event.relatedTarget ); // Button/link that triggered the modal
           var image = button.data( 'image' );    // Get the image URL from the data-image
                                                  // attribute of the button/link above.
           var modal = $( this );

           // Update the modal's content.
           modal.find('.modal-body').html(
               '<img src="' + image + '" alt="" />'
           );
       });
   });
   ```

Note that you should place the script in an external JavaScript file (e.g. in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/custom.js`) and load the file via the theme's `functions.php` file. Or wrap the script code with `<script>` and `</script>` tags and then add the script in the `footer.php` or `header.php` file. ( Check [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/) if you need help. You can also search on WPSE. :) )

And in the `modal-body` DIV, you don't need the `the_post_thumbnail()`.. or you can change it to `Loading...` or display a "special" image/content which serves similar purposes like a video's poster image. But then, it's just a *suggestion*. =)

Comment: thanks for this Sally _ I'm a bit confused tbh _ Did you get a chance to visit the page I linked to? Everything is working except that the wrong post / image is being displayed in the modal _ Whatever post is last added to the page is the one being displayed _ So i think this is more a question of using the inbuilt Wordpress post ID rather than relying on Bootstrap functionality to try and resolve the issue _ it's really how to use the Wordpress post ID is what I need _ but thanks again

Comment: Yes, I understand it - and you could try `wp_reset_postdata();` (which you should've called after the `endwhile`, anyway..) *but it won't work for what you're trying to do*. But you see, you'd only be using one modal; otherwise, you could move the modal into the `while` loop and the post ID would work. But really, the modal is a JavaScript thing and if you want to be able to display varying content, please consider trying what I suggested in the answer. And yes, the first thing I did after reading this question was visiting the link you provided.

Comment: aha! _ I only want to use one modal Sally _ but for it the same modal to display whichever image is clicked on _ I will add the wp_reset_postdata() as you stated but just to be clear _ Are you advising put all of the code for the modal inside the while loop? (Thanks for checking the link)

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm insisting that you try the suggestions in my answer... It worked well for me. Trust me! :D

Comment: "*the same modal to display whichever image is clicked on*" - yes, that is exactly what my answer is all about.

Comment: I just updated the page online _ with the modal code inside the while loop _ Now it's only showing the first image_ instead of the last image 
I wish I could use your suggestion Sally _ Problem is I can't really follow it _ sorry
(by that I mean I don't know where to put the jquery = in the footer.php?)
Also in option 2 _ I don't understand the reference to image in this code _ '<img src="' + image + '" alt="" />' 
You've taken so much time to help_ it's my incompetence that isn't helping _ which is why I'm sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93531/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-maik).

Comment: and not supposed to use comment to say thanks but I really am very grateful for your input : )

Comment: You're welcome, @maik. And although you already got it working, I revised the answer and hopefully it's more clear now - and helpful to other users as well. :) Cheers and all the best!